# How do I get into parental controls on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, parental-controls

I may be overlooking them. I want to set some controls for my little ones. But since I can't find the parental controls, I can't set them.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You want the *old* user accounts application not the the new metro one - the "Family Safety" settings link is hidden on the bottom left corner of that - thats the second one on the first row

[image]

Comment: Just want to add a quick guide on [how to use family safety](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57533877-285/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-8/) if he/she needs further information.

Comment: I hadn't really played with it. Does seem rather interesting should I ever need it (which I don't yet ;p)